# How do I fill a numpy array with its own coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a numpy *nr x nc* integer array, and I would like to fill in each element with its own array coordinates, represented as 2-tuples.  For example:

```
(0,0)    (0,1)    ... (0,nc-1)
 ...      ...     ...    ...
(nr-1,0) (nr-1,1) ... (nr-1,nc-1)
```

I am sure this can be done with list comprehensions but can't get my head around how, specifically.

Comment: Are you clear why you need such an array, as opposed to the kinds of arrays or tuple of arrays produced by the likes of `meshgrid` and `mgrid`?  What are you trying to do with this array?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to list comprehension: You could create a coordinate grid via meshgrid and into a grid:

```
i_coords, j_coords = np.meshgrid(range(nr), range(nc), indexing='ij')
coordinate_grid = np.array([i_coords, j_coords])
```

Lastly you just would have to convert the elements to tuples.

Comment: Thanks!  I was not familiar with np.meshgrid.   On your "lastly", how would I do that conversion?   Can I map "tuple" over the array?

Answer (score 0):

Got my head around it:

```
[ [(r,c) for c in range(nc) ] for r in range(nr) ]
```

Comment: I guess not...   This produces a two-dimensional list of tuples, but when I try to convert it to a 2D numpy of tuples, it instead comes out as a 3D array (nr,nc,2) of numbers.

Comment: A 2d array of tuples has to be `object` dtype, which is an inferior kind of array.  And hard to make.  This 3d array is, for most purposes, better.  Requiring tuples is most likely an unnecessary feature.